# What is the type of the webpack config function when it comes to TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I cannot figure out the type of the webpack configuring function when the config is written in TypeScript.

Currently I export an object whose type is `Configuration`:

```
const config: Configuration = {
  mode: 'production',
  // ...
}
export default config;
```

which should be changed to exporting a function:

```
export default (...): ... => {
  return {
    mode: 'production'
    // ...
  }
}
```

but I don't know the proper type of that function and cannot find it among the type definitions:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/types.d.ts

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like there's no well-established or recommended solution at the moment.

In the meantime, what I did was this.

`webpack.types.ts`:

```
import type { Configuration } from "webpack";
import type { Configuration as DevServerConfiguration } from "webpack-dev-server";

export interface WebpackConfiguration extends Configuration {
  devServer?: DevServerConfiguration;
}

type CLIValues = boolean | string;

type EnvValues = Record<string, CLIValues | Record<string, Env>>;

interface Env extends EnvValues {}

type Argv = Record<string, CLIValues>;

export interface WebpackConfigurationGenerator {
  (env?: Env, argv?: Argv): Configuration | Promise<Configuration>;
}
```

`webpack.config.ts`

```
import type { WebpackConfigurationGenerator } from "./webpack.types";

const generateConfig: WebpackConfigurationGenerator = (env, argv) => {
  // ...
};

export default generateConfig;
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure however, that one has to patch the Configuration type to add webpack-dev-server types - I believe it's done automatically (at least for me it somehow worked since I've installed `@types/webpack-dev-server` package). But the rest is quite clear, you implement the missing types :) Thanks! I just asked this question in their issue queue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14508 : maybe WE'RE missing something?